# Combobox closes automatically

Tags: wpf, combobox, controltemplate

I have restyled my combobox's template so that the drop down popup appears at the origin of the combobox. Here's how it's done:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
 <Grid>
  <ToggleButton/>
  <ContentPresenter/>
  <Popup PlacementRectangle="0,0,0,0" >
   <Grid Name="DropDown">
    ...
   </Grid>
  </Popup>
 </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The only problem I have with this is that when I click on the combobox it automatically selects the item the mouse is over and closes. The only way I can select any other item is by holding the mouse button and then moving the mouse over the wanted item. How to fix this?

Comment: Please add some more XAML or even better, a small working version so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the Popup Window IsOpen property to the toggle button, something like:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="myToggle" ClickMode="Press" />
<Popup x:Name="Popup"
  IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=myToggle}"
  PlacementRectangle="0,0,0,0"
  StaysOpen="False">
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and this solved my problem
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afa18ca4-0c4a-4a55-9d26-9c30afd4d767/wpf-combobox-closes-on-mouse-release-when-using-show-not-showdialog?forum=wpf. Hope it helps somebody.

To put out what is written in article :

Use `window.ShowDialog() instead of window.Show();`

> **"** When a Window containing a ComboBox is displayed using Show() instead
>   of ShowDialog() the popup list will close as soon as the mouse is
>   released, contrary to expected behavior of remaining open until a
>   selection is made or the control loses focus.**"**